# Pass variables to redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to pass two variables (strings) into a redux action. The purpose of this is the component knows the ID of the Company Profile it's trying to look up and we are getting that data using redux because this pattern is used in a couple places.

In the component:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.actions.getObject('Company', '16747fce-f0b1-422b-aa60-220c2dccac58')
}
```

In the action:

```
export function getObject(dataClass, dataId) {
  return {
    'BAQEND': {
      types: [
        GET_OBJECT,
        GET_OBJECT_SUCCESS,
        GET_OBJECT_FAILURE
      ],
      payload: (db) => db.(dataClass).load(dataId)
    }
  }
}
```

The `dataClass` is Company and the `dataID` is a guid.

My issue is I can't get the `dataClass` variable in there w/o throwing an error.  `dataID` works great.  If I were to change `payload: (db) => db.Company.load(dataId)` it works.

I've tried a couple things that did not work:

```
payload: (db) => db.dataClass.load(dataId)
payload: (db) => db.`${dataClass}`.load(dataId)
`payload: (db) => db.${dataClass}.load(dataId)`
```

Comment: `db[dataClass]`?

Comment: Nope, payload: (db) => db[dataClass].load(dataId) does not work either.  I think this might have something to do with the library I'm using.  I guess I'll just make an action and reducer for each dataClass... fortunately there are only four.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, `db` is an object which holds a key (property) of `Company`

```
db = {
  Company: 'someGuid'
}
```

If this is the case, then you can use the [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)  like this:
`db['Company']` Or `db[dataClass]`